# How to send jobs from multiple client threads to a pool of multiprocessor workers and get results returned (python)?

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I need to compute an expensive to compute function many times and want to use all processor cores for it. That would be relatively simple if I had all function argument sets at once: I could use multiprocessing pool.map . However I don't have them all at once, and also would like to avoid starting a separate process for each function computation. Therefore I want to start a pool of workers (no problems), send them the jobs from the clients (use queue, no problems), and then get the results back to the client (but how?).

More specifically, I need to compute my function on a multi-dimensional mesh array of arguments. In my case it is possible to avoid the computation for every array point by using two specific propeties of my function: it is monotonously nondecreasing for all arguments, and it can take only a few discrete values. Thus, if the function value is equal for two separate points on the mesh, it will be the same for all points in-between. Now we divide our mesh into parts and use recursion. Using recursion however means I cannot easily use pool.map

Actually I found a working solution, but guess there could be a more straightforward and reliable way.

I set up a separate dispatcher thread. It gets ALL results from the workers through a results queue, and then lets clients to pick up their results. Below the code for a simplified (2d) case.

EDIT: to the comment by Shihab Shahriar. Large part of the code needed to make the whole work, but do not directly relate to the question. Specifically:

`contpl()`, `sample_f()` are auxillary functions. In the real problem, instead of sample_f() there would be a complex and expensive simulation.

`recfill()` is the recursive function. It needs the resuls from the expensive calculation, and receives them via calling `getz()` . It would recursively start instances of itself in separate threads. Other details here unimportant.

`getz()` is an important part of my solution: It is a proxy between the above recursive function, and the workers pool. It sends the job parameters (tagged by `id`) via the queue `task_q` to the workers pool, then waits for events from the `dispatcher()` and checks if the calculated results already arrived, then returns them to it's caller. As the parent `recfill()` instances run in multiple threads, `getz()` too.

`Worker()` - instances of the class run in separate processes, wait for jobs arriving from the queue `task_q`, call the "expensive function", and put the results together with the `id` tag into the `result_queue` / `results_q`

`dispatcher()` runs in a separate thread, receives the results from `results_q` and puts them into a shared dict with the `id` as index. Then sends an event to `getz()` instances to check, whose result arrived.

`main` - starts workers, starts dispatcher, calls the `recfill()` , and cleans up.

---

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool
import multiprocessing
import threading

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def contpl(p1, p2, Z):
    """
    plots color density plot of XYZf
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.contourf(p1, p2, Z, 3, cmap='RdYlGn')
    plt.show()


def sample_f(x, y):
    """
    simple sample monotonous function to plot quater-circles
    returns integer values from 0 to 2
    """
    return np.round(1.4 * np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))


def getz(ix, iy, mp_params):
    """
    gets the values of the function sample_f for (x, y) values
    from the parameter arrays p1, p2 for the indices ix, iy
    if the value has not been already computed,
    send the job to a worker, then wait until the result is ready
    """
    task_q = mp_params["task_q"]
    result_event = mp_params["result_event"]
    result_dict = mp_params["result_dict"]
    num_workers = mp_params["num_workers"]
    results_q = mp_params["results_q"]

    z = Zarr[ix, iy]
    if z >= 0:
        return z     # nice, the point has already been calculated
    # otherwise z is -1 from the array initialisazion
    else:
        # compute "flattened index" of a point as id
        dims = Zarr.shape
        id = np.ravel_multi_index((ix, iy), dims)

        task_q.put((id, p1[ix, iy], p2[ix, iy])) # send the job, targeted by the id, to workers

        # not wait until dispatcher calls
        while True:
            result_event.wait()
            try:
                # anything for me?
                z = result_dict.pop(id)
                result_event.clear()
                break
            except KeyError:
                pass
        # now the point is computed, write the value into the array
        Zarr[ix, iy] = z
        return z

def recfill(ix, iy, mp_params):
    """
    recursive function to compute values of a monotonous function
    on a 2D square (sub-)array of parameters
    """

    (ix0, ix1) = ix # x indices
    (iy0, iy1) = iy # y indices

    z0 = getz(ix0, iy0, mp_params) # get the bottom left point

    # if the array size is one in all dimensions, we reached the recursion limit
    if (ix0 == ix1) and (iy0 == iy1):
        return

    else:
        # get the top right point
        z1 = getz(ix1, iy1, mp_params)
        # if the values for bottom left and top right are equal, they are the same for all
        # elements in between
        if z0 == z1:
            Zarr[ix0:ix1+1, iy0:iy1+1] = z0 # fill in the subarray
            return # and we are done for this recursion branch

        else:
            # divide the sub-array by half in each dimension
            xhalf = (ix1 - ix0 + 1) // 2
            yhalf = (iy1 - iy0 + 1) // 2

            ixlo = (ix0, ix0+xhalf-1)
            iylo = (iy0, iy0+yhalf-1)
            ixhi = (ix0+xhalf, ix1)
            iyhi = (iy0+yhalf, iy1)

            # prepare arguments for the map function
            l1 = [(ixlo, iylo), (ixlo, iyhi), (ixhi, iylo), (ixhi, iyhi)]
            (ixs, iys) = zip(*l1)
            mpps = [mp_params]*4

            # and now multithreaded recursive call for each quater of the initial sub-array
            with Pool() as p:
                p.map(recfill, ixs, iys, mpps)

            return


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    """
    adapted from
    https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html
    """
    def __init__(self, mp_params):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = mp_params["task_q"]
        self.result_queue = mp_params["results_q"]

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            job = self.task_queue.get()
            if job is None:
                print('{}: Exiting'.format(proc_name))
                break

            (id, x, y) = job
            result = sample_f(x, y)

            answer = (id, result)
            self.result_queue.put(answer)


def dispatcher(mp_params):
    """
    receives the computation results from the results queue,
    puts them into a shared dictionary,
    and notifies all clients per event,
    that they should check the dictionary,
    if there is anything for them
    """
    result_event = mp_params["result_event"]
    result_dict = mp_params["result_dict"]
    results_q = mp_params["results_q"]

    while True:
        qitem = results_q.get()
        if qitem is not None:
            (id, result) = qitem
            result_dict[id] = result
            result_event.set()
        else:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':

    result_event = threading.Event()
    num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    task_q = multiprocessing.SimpleQueue()
    results_q = multiprocessing.Queue() # why using SimpleQueue here would hang the program?
    result_dict = {}


    mp_params = {}
    mp_params["task_q"] = task_q
    mp_params["results_q"] = results_q
    mp_params["result_dict"] = result_dict
    mp_params["result_event"] = result_event
    mp_params["num_workers"] = num_workers


    print('Creating {} workers'.format(num_workers))

    workers = [Worker(mp_params) for i in range(num_workers)]
    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    # creating dispatcher thread
    t = threading.Thread(target=dispatcher, args=(mp_params, ))
    t.start()

    # creating parameter arrays
    arrsize = 128
    xvec = np.linspace(0, 1, arrsize)
    yvec =    np.linspace(0, 1, arrsize)
    (p1, p2) = np.meshgrid(xvec, yvec)

    # initialize the results array
    # our sample_f returns only non-negative values
    # therefore fill in with -1 to indicate the values
    # which have not been computed yet
    Zarr = np.full_like(p1, -1, dtype=np.int8)

    # now call our recursive function
    # to compute all array values
    recfill((0,arrsize-1), (0,arrsize-1), mp_params)

    # clean up
    for i in range(num_workers):
        task_q.put(None) # stop all workers

    results_q.put(None) # stop dispatcher
    t.join()

    # plot the results
    contpl(p1, p2, Zarr)


    # and check the results by comparing with directly
    # calculated values
    Z = sample_f(p1, p2)
    assert np.all(Z == Zarr)
```

Comment: Can you describe your code, specially important parts you talked about. Is everything in this pretty big code directly related to your question?

Comment: Shihab Shahriar, thank you, I added some explanations now. See also comments in the source.